# Error with easy_install for Numpy 1.9.1

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, virtualenv

I am trying to install [numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.1/) to a Python 2.7 virtual environment. But I get the error below.

> C:\Python\2.7.5\x86....\packages\numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
>   **is not a valid distutils Windows .exe**

A full trace of the error is as below, does anyone have a clue why I am getting this? I have tried googling but there isn't much information. The [link(s)](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2006-September/006728.html) I found suggested this was an `easy_install` issue but I am not sure how it is solved.

```
PYTHONHOME is set.  You *must* activate the virtualenv before using it
New python executable in C:\Project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools................done.
Installing pip...................done.
Installing package  pytz-2014.3-py2.7.egg
Processing pytz-2014.3-py2.7.egg
creating c:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.3-py2.7.egg
Extracting pytz-2014.3-py2.7.egg to c:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages
Adding pytz 2014.3 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\Project\venv\lib\site-pac
kages\pytz-2014.3-py2.7.egg
Installing package  python-dateutil-2.1.tar.gz
Processing python-dateutil-2.1.tar.gz
Running python-dateutil-2.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\zhubarb\ap
pdata\local\temp\easy_install-wxuxb4\python-dateutil-2.1\egg-dist-tmp-c266dq
Adding python-dateutil 2.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.1-py2.7.egg
Installing package  numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
Processing numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
error: C:\Python\2.7.5\x86\..\..\packages\numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe 
is not a valid distutils Windows .exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    python_packages = python_packages
  File "C:\projects\process.py", line 840, in set_up
    builder.setup_python(python_packages)
  File "C:\projects\process.py", line 709, in set_up_python
    (venv_python, os.path.join(python_package_dir, package)), shell=True)
  File "C:\Python\2.7.5\x86\lib\subprocess.py", line 542, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\Project\venv\scripts\python -u -m easy_
install --no-deps --always-unzip C:\Python\2.7.5\x86\..\..\packages\
numpy-1.9.1-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Numpy via anaconda.  http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html

Numpy is notoriously difficult to install because of the C dependencies and anaconda helps install it anywhere.

Comment: thanks but I need to install just numpy and to a virtualenv. And it needs to be compact so I do not want to include a suite of packages that the project does not use.